# Устранение лишних секций в секционированных таблицах при запросе SELECT, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

PostgresSQL 12

Подскажите пожалуйста, я делаю такого рода запросы

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM subject_position_info spi
WHERE spi.period_id IN (SELECT p.period_id
    FROM periods p
    WHERE p.quarter = 1
      AND p.year = 2019
);

SELECT count(*)
FROM subject_position_info_old spi
WHERE spi.period_id IN (SELECT p.period_id
    FROM periods p
    WHERE p.quarter = 1
      AND p.year = 2019
);
```

subject_position_info - таблица секционированная Декларативно по ключу period_id

subject_position_info_old вторая обычная

Данные одинаковые

Вложенный SELECT возвращает 1 значение, цифру 5 (но если убрать p.quarter = 1, будет 4 числа поэтому только IN)

Разницы в скорости выполнения этих запросов нет ни какой, всё равно сканируются все партиции

Если же указать в место вложенного SELECT , IN (5). то выбирается только та партиция которая нужна и время выполнения уже отличается на порядки  доли секунды и минуты.

Если заменить IN на = , отсечение начинает работать нормально, но такой вариант не подходит

Eсли в IN задать в ручную (5,6,7,8) тоже работает , но интересен только SELECT

Нужно добиться динамического отсечения партиций во время выполнения запроса, которое анонсировано в документации

Это EXPLAIN запроса к партицированной таблице https://explain.depesz.com/s/wQeQ

Это к обычной
https://explain.depesz.com/s/nl1dQ

Это когда SELECT count(*) FROM subject_position_info spi WHERE spi.period_id IN( 5 );
https://explain.depesz.com/s/4hE2

ВОПРОС : Как заставить работать динамическое отсечение партиций во время выполнения запроса ? (В документации написано что это так и работает , на практике нет :( ) , может дело в версии PostgresSQL ? (проверить пока возможности нет)

Comment: В документации про динамические значения написано "may", что означает "может", а не "должно". `Partition pruning may also be performed here to remove partitions using values which are only known during actual query execution. `

Comment: По плану видно, что он по таблице `periods` делает Seq Scan - я думаю, в этом причина. Попробуй уникальный индекc сделать `periods(year, quater)`

Comment: сделал https://explain.depesz.com/s/DKSL
время выполнения не изменилось, сканирует все партиции

Comment: Ладно may , но когда этот may срабатывает , что бы мне хотя бы понимать на что мне можно 100% рассчитывать, тогда я буду от этого отталкиваться

Comment: "время выполнения не изменилось, сканирует все партиции" ну так он и индекс не использует. Могу только посоветовать закэшировать periods.id на клиенте и подставлять их.

Comment: "что бы мне хотя бы понимать на что мне можно 100% рассчитывать" - если он делает Seq Scan, то он не может предсказать какие партиции понадобятся, поэтому читает все. А если `IN ()` заменить на `inner join periods p on spi.period_id=p.period_id and p.quarter = 1 AND p.year = 2019`?

Comment: Это пробовал :( тоже самое (полный скан , время тоже)

SELECT count(*)
FROM subject_position_info spi
inner join periods p on spi.period_id=p.period_id and p.quarter = 1 AND p.year = 2019;